# What is the most elegant way to express conditional independence on a line graph?

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process, graphical-model, conditional-independence

Consider a Markov graph

$$x_1 -x_2-x_3-...-x_t$$

In such a graphical model, we have the conditional independence property $x_{s-1} \perp x_{s+1:t} | x_s \;\forall\; x=2,...,t-1$ and $x_{1:s-1} \perp x_{s+1} | x_s \;\forall\; x=2,...,t-1$, that is to say, each node $x_s$ is independent of all nodes beyond its immediate neighbour (either $x_{s-1}$ or $x_{s+1}$).

**Now my question**: The expressions above are alright, but I don't like the fact that I have to specify that it holds both ways (to the left and right). Is there an elegant, compact way to express this conditional independence in a single expression?

I thought about $x_{s-1} \perp x_{s+1} | x_s \;\forall\; x=2,...,t-1$, but I don't think this captures that for example $$x_{4} \perp x_{1} | x_2 $$